# Oracle APEX - Stop Primary Key Default Value 't1000' on Page

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX Page Designer. I have a master detail page. For both the master and the detail sections, the page defaults the value of the primary key to 't1000' every time I insert a new record. If I insert more that one new record, it increments the number.

- I do not have a sequence tied to the value in the table definition.
- When inserting in SQL workshop, no default value is shown
- On page, Default value is set to "SQL Query" with query of "select null from dual"

I want the new records to be blank.

Comment: Did you try removing the default value?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid t1000 in your Master Detail Page or Interactive Grid, you can use ROWID as primary key.

Take a look at this example:

[ROWID as Primary Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auqwv.png)